# Calling context.getImgData() causes canvas to "flicker"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm streaming a webcam feed into a `video` element, and then painting that onto a `canvas` element. I'm then running a face detection algorithm on the canvas to paint a square over the face.

The issue is that to do this, I need to call the `context.getImgData()` method. This is causing the canvas to "flicker" when the method is called. It turns completely black for a split second then returns to normal. It looks terrible. I've followed some examples of others who have drawn on canvases with webcam feeds, and they also use this method, so I don't really know of a way of getting around it.

I have some sample code below that works in JSfiddle. I'm on mac OS using firefox. There are two buttons. The first paints the stream from the `video` element into the `canvas`, and the second simply runs `getImgData()`. You can clearly see the issue I'm describing. Any thoughts?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="paintCanvas()">paint</button>
        <button onclick="testFunc()">test</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="375"></canvas>
        <video autoplay loop="false" src="media/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="videoElement">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var myContext = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            // vid2.srcObject = stream;
            // document.getElementById('controls').innerHTML = "Switch back to video for player controls";
            // document.getElementById('timing').innerHTML = '';
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            media = 'video';
            console.log(err.name);
        });
    let ch, cw;
    function paintCanvas(e) {
        console.log('painting canvas')
        const v = document.getElementById('videoElement');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth);
        ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight);
        canvas.width = cw;
        canvas.height = ch;

        draw(v, context, cw, ch);
    }
    function draw(v, c, w, h) {
        // console.log('drawing')
        videoRunning = true;
        if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
        c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
        myVar = setTimeout(draw, 60, v, c, w, h);
    }
    function testFunc() {       
        // setInterval(function () {
            console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
            x = myContext.getImageData(0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
            console.log(x);
        // }, 200);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. With what browsers and OSes did you test?

Comment: Sorry should've clarified - mac os and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out - if you're looking to use the `getImageData()` method it must be called within the same function as the draw.

```
function draw(v, c, w, h) {
    // console.log('drawing')
    videoRunning = true;
    if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
    myVar = setTimeout(draw, 60, v, c, w, h);
    x = myContext.getImageData(0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)

}
```

Comment: Nope no reason it should be called in the same function. Your problem has more to do with your terrible loop, use rAF instead. Also, you would probably win by keeping an smaller offscreen canvas, on which you would draw a shrinked version of the video frames to do the detection on a smaller surface.